# Display different values from same data set in one query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that shows our abandonment rate, however we want to see how many of these abandonments were abandoned after 6 seconds of ringing.

Currently I get my results as:

```
count | queue | waittime
```

I want it displayed as:

```
count | count6 | queue | waittime
```

The query is:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count,queue,sum(info3) as waittime FROM queue_stats
LEFT JOIN qevent ON qevent=qevent.event_id
LEFT JOIN qname ON qname=qname.queue_id
WHERE datetime>=CURDATE() AND event IN ('ABANDON','EXITWITHKEY','EXITWITHTIMEOUT','EXITEMPTY') 
GROUP BY qname 
ORDER BY null
```

To get the value of calls abandoned over 6 seconds, I add `AND info3 > 6`just before GROUP BY.

Any suggestions how I can have it in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional counting - include the condition within the count() (or sum()) function:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count,
       count(if(info3 > 6, 1, null)) as six_count,
       queue,
       sum(info3) as waittime
FROM queue_stats
LEFT JOIN qevent ON qevent=qevent.event_id
LEFT JOIN qname ON qname=qname.queue_id
WHERE datetime>=CURDATE() AND event IN ('ABANDON','EXITWITHKEY','EXITWITHTIMEOUT','EXITEMPTY') 
GROUP BY qname 
ORDER BY null
```

You can use a `case` expression in place of the `if()` function as well.

Comment: Thanks! This works great.
I'll have to read up about this, haven't used conditions like this before.